# Sum of Multiples of 3 and 5 using Methods: Incorrect sum coming

Tags: java

I have been trying to solve Project Euler Problem #1 using "methods" in Java. It is giving correct multiples. However, sum is not coming right. Here are my codes:

**Method Class:**

```
package lessons;

public class method {
       int a,b, add; 
    public void multipleThree()
    {
        for (a=3; a<1000; a+=3)
        {
        System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
public void multipleFive(){
    for (b=5; b<1000; b+=5)
        {
        System.out.println(b);
}       
}
public void sum(){
    add= a+b;
    System.out.println("The sum is "+ add);
}
}
```

**Main Class**

```
package lessons;

public class Lessons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

      method problem = new method();
      problem.multipleThree();
      problem.multipleFive();
      problem.sum();
     }}
```

Any helps???

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't give right sum. What is the expected o/p and what are you getting?

Comment: Where have you set initial values for a,b? You are getting correct multiples because a,b are initialized in loop, but this is not the case in sum method. Hope you are getting my point.

Comment: what u r expecting from this program.. please remove the conflict first.. 

Hope u should learn and try `this` keyword. this may help u out..
bydway your code will compiles fine but you are not initializing the gloabal variable `a and b`. So, `this` keyword will help u out

Thank You

Comment: You `did not initialized a or b` .. and you did not mention what was your `expected output?`

Comment: Thank you everyone! I got my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a+b` is calculated once - outside your loop. The result will be the sum of the *final* values of `a` and `b`. If you want to sum each element in each loop, you'll need to update `add` inside the loops:

```
public class method {
    int add = 0; 

    public void multipleThree() {
        for (int a=3; a<1000; a+=3) {
            System.out.println(a);
            add += a;
        }
    }

    public void multipleFive(){
        for (int b=5; b<1000; b+=5) {
            System.out.println(b);
            add += b;
        }
    }

    public void sum(){
        System.out.println("The sum is "+ add);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The output for `multipleThree()` and `multipleFive()` is 999 and 995 accordingly. However `a` and `b` are incremented in the `for` loops one more time to meet the exit condition therefor their sum is 2002 and not 1994.

You can change `sum()` to this

```
public void sum(){
    add = a + b - 8;
    System.out.println("The sum is "+ add);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below

```
package lessons;

public class method {
int a,b, add; 
 public void multipleThree()
{
 for (a=3; a<1000; a+=3)
 {
 System.out.println(a);
 }
 a=a-3;//added this
}
 public void multipleFive(){
for (b=5; b<1000; b+=5)
 {
 System.out.println(b);
}       
b=b-5;//added this
}
public void sum(){
  add= a+b;
  System.out.println("The sum is "+ add);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare variables separately,

```
class method {
    int i, j, add;

    public void multipleThree() {
        for (int a = 3; a < 1000; a = a + 3) {
            System.out.println(a);
            i = a;
        }
    }

    public void multipleFive() {
        for (int b = 5; b < 1000; b = b + 5) {
            System.out.println(b);
            j = b;
        }
    }

    public void sum() {
        add = i + j;
        System.out.println("The sum is " + add);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        Scanner z = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = z.nextInt();
        while(N!=0)
            {
            long number = z.nextInt();
            long p = (number-1)/3;
            long sum1 = (p*(6+((p-1)*3)))/2;
            long q = (number-1)/5;
            long sum2 = (q*(10+((q-1)*5)))/2;  
            long r = (number-1)/15;
            long sum3 = (r*(30+((r-1)*15)))/2;  
            System.out.println(sum1+sum2-sum3);
        }
    }
}
```

This is best way to solve the given problem passed all test cases.Happy coding

Comment: p and q to calculate 3 and 5 products r to calculate products of 15 as consider an example where 30 then it is divisible by both 3 and 5 it comes twice so i subtracted sum3 from resultant sum.

Comment: Nice... but not *exactly* the answer to OP's question. And you can reduce duplication with a method `long sum(int n, int m) { long p = (n-1)/m; return (p*((m*2)+((p-1)*m)))/2; }`.